# Why do Angular 2 Quickstart tutorial libraries break when concatenated?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm following the basic [Angular 2 Quickstart tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html). In this tutorial, the simple application requires these dependency libraries:

**Index.html**

```
 <html>
    ...

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    ...
</html>
```

Everything goes fine and the application works when the libraries are loaded in this way. But, if I  concatenate these libraries (keeping order) in one single file, the application break.

**Index.html**

```
 <html>
    ...

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="/concatenated-libs.js"></script>        

    ...
</html>
```

This is the console output error:

[image]

The error occurs in the `es6-shim.js` file.

[image]

Does anynone know how to deal with it?

Regards,

Bernardo

Comment: How do you concat them? Do you maintain newlines between the files?

Comment: Sure, I concatenated them using [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat).

Comment: i am having the same problem with angular2 beta7, they broke in a different place, but broke on concatenation

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. I got it working after making some order changes in gulp src as below:

```
    libfiles: [
        'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
        'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
        'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
  'node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js',
        'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js',
        'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
        'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
        'node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.min.js',
        'node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js'
    ]
```

Apparently, when importing individual js files, we get lucky with the proper order which is not the case with gulp concat. Hope this helps.